# PHPMailer sent but not delivered

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I have this debug code from my PHPMailer, it says the message was successfully sent, but I don't see any incoming email on my Gmail and other email. I've checked SPAM folder too, but nothing there.

here's the debug message :

```
2015-02-03 03:44:33 Connection: opening to localhost:26, t=300, opt=array ( ) 
2015-02-03 03:44:33 Connection: opened 
2015-02-03 03:44:33 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220-la03.dewaweb.com ESMTP Exim 4.84 #2 Mon, 02 Feb 2015 19:44:33 -0800 220-We do not authorize the use of this system to transport unsolicited, 220 and/or bulk e-mail. 
2015-02-03 03:44:33 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO *****.com 
2015-02-03 03:44:33 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-la03.dewaweb.com Hello localhost [127.0.0.1] 250-SIZE 52428800 250-8BITMIME 250-PIPELINING 250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN 250-STARTTLS 250 HELP 
2015-02-03 03:44:33 CLIENT -> SERVER: STARTTLS 
2015-02-03 03:44:33 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 TLS go ahead 
2015-02-03 03:44:33 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO *****.com 
2015-02-03 03:44:33 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-la03.dewaweb.com Hello localhost [127.0.0.1] 250-SIZE 52428800 250-8BITMIME 250-PIPELINING 250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN 250 HELP 2015-02-03 03:44:33  CLIENT -> SERVER: AUTH LOGIN 
2015-02-03 03:44:33 SERVER -> CLIENT: 334 VXNlcm5hbWU6 
2015-02-03 03:44:33 CLIENT -> SERVER: bm8tcmVwbHlAZW1pdm9zb2x1dGlvbnMuY29t 
2015-02-03 03:44:33 SERVER -> CLIENT: 334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6 
2015-02-03 03:44:33 CLIENT -> SERVER: THVhcmJpYXNhSDg4MSE= 
2015-02-03 03:44:33 SERVER -> CLIENT: 235 Authentication succeeded 
2015-02-03 03:44:33 CLIENT -> SERVER: MAIL FROM: 
2015-02-03 03:44:33 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250 OK 
2015-02-03 03:44:33 CLIENT -> SERVER: RCPT TO: 
2015-02-03 03:44:33 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250 Accepted 
2015-02-03 03:44:33 CLIENT -> SERVER: DATA 
2015-02-03 03:44:33 SERVER -> CLIENT: 354 Enter message, ending with "." on a line by itself 
2015-02-03 03:44:33 CLIENT -> SERVER: Date: Tue, 3 Feb 2015 10:44:33 +0700 
2015-02-03 03:44:33 CLIENT -> SERVER: To: no-reply@*****.com 
2015-02-03 03:44:33 CLIENT -> SERVER: From: "*****.com" 
2015-02-03 03:44:33 CLIENT -> SERVER: Reply-To: *****@gmail.com 
2015-02-03 03:44:33 CLIENT -> SERVER: Subject: Segera Aktifkan Account Anda 
2015-02-03 03:44:33 CLIENT -> SERVER: Message-ID: <9cd5d51370aedccf9154c8d87f109caf@*****.com> 
2015-02-03 03:44:33 CLIENT -> SERVER: X-Priority: 3 
2015-02-03 03:44:33 CLIENT -> SERVER: X-Mailer: PHPMailer 5.2.9 (https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/) 
2015-02-03 03:44:33 CLIENT -> SERVER: MIME-Version: 1.0 
2015-02-03 03:44:33 CLIENT -> SERVER: Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1 
2015-02-03 03:44:33 CLIENT -> SERVER: Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit 
2015-02-03 03:44:33 CLIENT -> SERVER: 
2015-02-03 03:44:33 CLIENT -> SERVER: Halo, Robert
2015-02-03 03:44:33 CLIENT -> SERVER: . 
2015-02-03 03:44:33 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250 OK id=1YIUPh-002egj-8a 
2015-02-03 03:44:33 CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT 
2015-02-03 03:44:33 SERVER -> CLIENT: 221 la03.dewaweb.com closing connection 
2015-02-03 03:44:33 Connection: closed 
2015-02-03 03:44:33 Connection: opening to localhost:26, t=300, opt=array ( ) 
2015-02-03 03:44:33 Connection: opened 
2015-02-03 03:44:33 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220-la03.dewaweb.com ESMTP Exim 4.84 #2 Mon, 02 Feb 2015 19:44:33 -0800 220-We do not authorize the use of this system to transport unsolicited, 220 and/or bulk e-mail. 
2015-02-03 03:44:33 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO *****.com 
2015-02-03 03:44:33 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-la03.dewaweb.com Hello localhost [127.0.0.1] 250-SIZE 52428800 250-8BITMIME 250-PIPELINING 250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN 250-STARTTLS 250 HELP 
2015-02-03 03:44:33 CLIENT -> SERVER: STARTTLS 
2015-02-03 03:44:33 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 TLS go ahead 
2015-02-03 03:44:33 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO *****.com 
2015-02-03 03:44:33 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-la03.dewaweb.com Hello localhost [127.0.0.1] 250-SIZE 52428800 250-8BITMIME 250-PIPELINING 250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN 250 HELP 
2015-02-03 03:44:33 CLIENT -> SERVER: AUTH LOGIN 
2015-02-03 03:44:33 SERVER -> CLIENT: 334 VXNlcm5hbWU6 
2015-02-03 03:44:33 CLIENT -> SERVER: bm8tcmVwbHlAZW1pdm9zb2x1dGlvbnMuY29t 
2015-02-03 03:44:33 SERVER -> CLIENT: 334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6 
2015-02-03 03:44:33 CLIENT -> SERVER: THVhcmJpYXNhSDg4MSE= 
2015-02-03 03:44:33 SERVER -> CLIENT: 235 Authentication succeeded 
2015-02-03 03:44:33 CLIENT -> SERVER: MAIL FROM: 
2015-02-03 03:44:33 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250 OK 
2015-02-03 03:44:33 CLIENT -> SERVER: RCPT TO: 
2015-02-03 03:44:33 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250 Accepted 
2015-02-03 03:44:33 CLIENT -> SERVER: DATA 
2015-02-03 03:44:33 SERVER -> CLIENT: 354 Enter message, ending with "." on a line by itself 
2015-02-03 03:44:33 CLIENT -> SERVER: Date: Tue, 3 Feb 2015 10:44:33 +0700 
2015-02-03 03:44:33 CLIENT -> SERVER: To: no-reply@*****.com 
2015-02-03 03:44:33 CLIENT -> SERVER: From: "*****.com" 
2015-02-03 03:44:33 CLIENT -> SERVER: Reply-To: *****@gmail.com 
2015-02-03 03:44:33 CLIENT -> SERVER: Subject: Segera Aktifkan Account Anda 
2015-02-03 03:44:33 CLIENT -> SERVER: Message-ID: 
2015-02-03 03:44:33 CLIENT -> SERVER: X-Priority: 3 
2015-02-03 03:44:33 CLIENT -> SERVER: X-Mailer: PHPMailer 5.2.9 (https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/) 
2015-02-03 03:44:33 CLIENT -> SERVER: MIME-Version: 1.0 
2015-02-03 03:44:33 CLIENT -> SERVER: Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1 
2015-02-03 03:44:33 CLIENT -> SERVER: Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit 
2015-02-03 03:44:33 CLIENT -> SERVER: 
2015-02-03 03:44:33 CLIENT -> SERVER: Halo, Robert
2015-02-03 03:44:33 CLIENT -> SERVER: . 
2015-02-03 03:44:33 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250 OK id=1YIUPh-002egn-EI 
2015-02-03 03:44:33 CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT 
2015-02-03 03:44:33 SERVER -> CLIENT: 221 la03.dewaweb.com closing connection 
2015-02-03 03:44:33 Connection: closed 
Message sent!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your local mail server is accepting the message successfully, but apparently it's not getting anywhere beyond that. It could be bouncing for some reason, or outbound could be broken. You will need to look in your mail server logs to see what has happened to it, or you could try sending directly to your gmail address.